# Trigger email to the corresponding email address

Tags: php, mysql

I'm generating a table using this code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$row['rollNo']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['bgroup']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['first_name']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['last_name']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['phone']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['e_mail']}</td>";
            echo "<td><input type='button' value='Send Email'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

The output:

[image: Generated table]

When I click on `Send Email`, I want to trigger an email to the email corresponding to the button. How can I send the email address beside the button as input to the `mail()` function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I would make a form per row with a hidden input that had the id of the person in your database. When they hit the Send Mail, reload the page, check the db for the id in the post, grab the user info, send the email based on the populated address from db. That's probably what I'd do anyway. Also use `mail()` not `email()`...unless you are using some library that has a function named `email()`

Comment: @Rasclatt Can you make it a bit clearer? Rookie here! I will generate something like `<tr><td> <form></form></td></tr>` with hidden input - the primary key - then grab the email address from the table and send it as input to the function? Can you write a piece of dummy line for the "form per row with a hidden input", please? Also, `email()` was a typo. I'm using `mail()`. :)

Comment: Note, I made an error on my Submit input...I forgot to name it "submit"! That is important or the processing part won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to your comment for clarity, I would do something like this:

```
// Top of page:
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // check the $_POST['id'] against your db
    // if you have it in the db (you should!)
    // send using the mail()
}


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <td><?php echo $row['rollNo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['bgroup']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo {$row['first_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['e_mail']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <!-- hidden input here with the id (or whatever your auto incremented/unique value is in your table) -->
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email"></td>
        </form>
    </tr><?php
    } ?>
```

*As a side note, you should not be using the **mysql_** library/functions. It is insecure and scheduled for deprecation in future versions of PHP. One day you will wake up and find none of your db code works anymore!*